# Linker script for C++ program for LM3S8962 unhosted using Codesourcery lite toolchain?

Tags: c++, embedded, g++, ld, cortex-m

Does anyone have a linker script specifically for the Stellaris LM3S8962 board or could explain how to create one?  I am using the codesourcery g++ lite toolchain and can successfully create the elf file for the hosted environment using this linker script:

- [Hosted Linker Script](https://gist.github.com/789401)

This does not work with the unhosted libraries.  All the examples on I have found only work for C and not C++ and there seems to be some magic involved regarding the cs3 startup code.  Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I have seen some scripts for C++, but for STM32. I can imagine it being much different.

Comment: Could you point me to an example?

Comment: I have just noticed that you are not using the barebones toolchain, but the GNU one. Are you looking for a barebones solution? If so, you need to download the 'arm-none-eabi' toolchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the extra sections in a C++ linker script (from STM32):

```
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
```

The somewhere in your startup, you need to call:

```
bl __libc_init_array
```

If you use http://www.google.com/codesearch, you should be able to find something device specific.

Comment: Thanks leppie, this pushed me in the right direction.  I have accepted your answer and posted my final solution in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've ended up with:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-bigarm", "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
GROUP(crti.o crtn.o crtbegin.o crtend.o)
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)                                         /* entry Point */

MEMORY {                                           /* memory map of LM3S811 */
    ROM (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 256K
    RAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64K
}

/* The size of the stack used by the application. NOTE: you need to adjust  */
STACK_SIZE = 24K;


/* The size of the heap used by the application. NOTE: you need to adjust   */
HEAP_SIZE = 0K;

SECTIONS {
    .  = 0x0;
    .isr_vector : {                 /* the vector table goes FIRST into ROM */
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))                                /* vector table */
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >ROM

    .text : {                                         /* code and constants */
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.text)                                   /* .text sections (code) */
        *(.text*)                                 /* .text* sections (code) */
        *(.rodata)           /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
        *(.rodata*)         /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */

        KEEP (*(.init))
        KEEP (*(.fini))

        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >ROM

    __exidx_start = .;
    .ARM.exidx : {
        *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    } >ROM
    __exidx_end = .;


    .preinit_array : {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
        KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    } >ROM

    .init_array : {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
        KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.init_array*))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    } >ROM

    .fini_array : {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
        KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    } >ROM




    _etext = .;                            /* global symbols at end of code */
    .vtable : {                 /* the vector table goes FIRST into RAM */
        KEEP(*(.vtable))                                /* vector table */
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >RAM
    .data :  AT (_etext) {
        __data_load = LOADADDR (.data);
        __data_start = .;
        *(.data)                                          /* .data sections */
        *(.data*)                                        /* .data* sections */
        . = ALIGN(7);
        __data_end__ = .;
        _edata = __data_end__;
    } >RAM

    .bss : {
        __bss_start__ = . ;
        *(.bss)
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = .;                     /* define a global symbol at bss end */
        __bss_end__ = .;
    } >RAM

    PROVIDE ( end = _ebss );
    PROVIDE ( _end = _ebss );
    PROVIDE ( __end__ = _ebss );

    .heap : {
        __heap_start__ = . ;
        . = . + HEAP_SIZE;
        . = ALIGN(8);
        __heap_end__ = . ;
    } >RAM

    .stack : {
        __stack_start__ = . ;
        . = . + STACK_SIZE;
        . = ALIGN(8);
        __c_stack_top__ = . ;
        __stack_end__ = . ;
    } >RAM

    /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
    /DISCARD/ : {
        libc.a ( * )
        libm.a ( * )
        libgcc.a ( * )
    }
}
```